# Jinja templating, how to nest html into containers via loops?

Tags: python, jinja2

So I want rows and within each row container there will be three container elements. I attempted to loop through and for every mod 3, it'll create a new row container, but how do I make it such that each subsequent container will be nested inside the row container?

Below is something I tried working with but it didn't work.

```
{% for post in posts %}
 {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 0 %}
   <div class="container-fluid">
 {% endif %}

<div> ... </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 2 %}
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
    {% endif %}
    <div> ... </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't

Comment: Maybe provide an example of the HTML you're trying to achieve?